# Reconstructing from class to functional hook component in react

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components, react-hooks, state

Just wanted to redesign my application from class based components to functional hook based components and get sucked with this callback setState code block and can't achieve this with a working hook:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    items: [
      ...prevState.items,
      {
        itemtitle: '',
        description: '',
        articlenr: '',
        amount: '',
        unit: '',
        price: '',
        taxpercentage: '',
        total: ''
      }
    ],
    showItemDetail: true
  }))
```

Comment: In function component there is no `this.setState()`. Instead you need to use [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: I know, above is the working code I wanted to translate to work with hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to translate this to hooks? If so, you will have to post how your state looks like.

If your state is the whole object, you can do it like this

```
import react, {useState} from "react";

const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const [showItemDetail, setShowItemDetail] = useState(false)

setItems(items => [...items,
      {
        itemtitle: '',
        description: '',
        articlenr: '',
        amount: '',
        unit: '',
        price: '',
        taxpercentage: '',
        total: ''
      }
    ]
  )

setShowItemDetail(true)
```

Comment: `const [items, setItems] = useState([{ itemtitle: "", description: "", articlenr: "", amount: "", unit: "", price: "", taxpercentage: "", total: "" }])`

Comment: `const [showItemDetail, setShowItemDetail] = useState(false)`

Comment: You will have to update each state separately, I updated the answer to reflect that